D3 Issue with custom link strength on update


<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    svg {
      border: 1px black solid;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button id='btnRenderExisting2Node'>Render 2 existing nodes</button>
      <button id='btnRenderExisting3Node'>Render 3 existing nodes</button>
      <button id='btnRenderNewNode'>Render 3 existing nodes and 1 brand new node</button>
    </div>
    <svg width="250" height="250"></svg>
  </div>
  <script>
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      width = 250,
      height = 250,
      color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var a = {
        id: "a"
      },
      b = {
        id: "b"
      },
      c = {
        id: "c"
      },
      nodes = [a, b, c],
      l_ab = {
        source: a,
        target: b
      },
      l_bc = {
        source: b,
        target: c
      },
      l_ca = {
        source: c,
        target: a
      },
      links = [l_ab, l_bc, l_ca];

    var id = 0;

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
      .force('link', d3.forceLink().links(links).strength(d => {
        console.log(d);
        return 1;
      }))
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
      .alphaTarget(1)
      .on("tick", ticked)
      .stop();

    var g = svg.append("g"),
      link = g.append("g").attr("stroke", "#000").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".link"),
      node = g.append("g").attr("stroke", "#fff").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".node");

    function restart() {
      node = node.data(nodes);
      link = link.data(links);

      node.exit().transition().attr("r", 0).remove();
      link.exit().transition().attr("stroke-opacity", 0).remove();

      node = node.enter().append("circle")
        .attr("fill", d => color(d.id))
        .call(node => node.transition().attr("r", 8))
        .merge(node);

      link = link.enter().append("line")
        .call(link => link.transition().attr("stroke-opacity", 1))
        .merge(link);

      simulation.nodes(nodes);
      simulation.force("link").links(links)
        .strength(d => {
          console.log(d);
          return 1;
        });
      simulation.alpha(1).restart();
    }

    function ticked() {
      node.attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.y);

      link.attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);
    }

    restart();

    document.getElementById('btnRenderExisting3Node').addEventListener('click', function() {
      nodes = [a, b, c];
      links = [l_ab, l_bc, l_ca];
      restart();
    });

    document.getElementById('btnRenderExisting2Node').addEventListener('click', function() {
      nodes = [a, b];
      links = [l_ab];
      restart();
    });

    document.getElementById('btnRenderNewNode').addEventListener('click', function() {
      var d = {
        id: id++,
        x: width / 2,
        y: height / 2
      };
      nodes = [a, b, c, d];
      links = [l_ab, l_bc, l_ca, {
        source: a,
        target: d
      }];
      restart();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>



I need to refresh a d3 force graph with new data and also have a custom link strength, based on the properties of the edges.
This issue I run into happens when I use a custom link strength function and restart the simulation using the restart() function.
simulation.force("link").links(links)
    .strength(d => {
        console.log(d);
        return 1;
    });

The first time this runs, d will iterate over a different number of links and has unexpected behavior.  Likewise, I find that if I try to redefine the strength function to return a different value, it keeps resorting to the original function.
Run 1
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 0}
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 1}
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 2}

Run 2
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 1}
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 2}
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 0}
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 1}
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 2}
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 3}
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 0}
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 1}
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 2}
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 3}

Run 3
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 0}
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 1}
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 2}
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 3}
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 0}
>>{source: {…}, target: {…}, index: 0}

It is seemingly unpredictable what it will output and sometimes uses data that isn't from the current dataset.  Why is this happening and is there anything I can do to mitigate the problem?
Full HTML Code:
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        svg {
            border: 1px black solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <button id='btnRenderExisting2Node'>Render 2 existing nodes</button>
            <button id='btnRenderExisting3Node'>Render 3 existing nodes</button>
            <button id='btnRenderNewNode'>Render 3 existing nodes and 1 brand new node</button>
        </div>
        <svg width="250" height="250"></svg>
    </div>
    <script>
        var test = true;
        var svg = d3.select("svg"),
            width = 250,
            height = 250,
            color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

        var a = {
                id: "a"
            },
            b = {
                id: "b"
            },
            c = {
                id: "c"
            },
            nodes = [a, b, c],
            l_ab = {
                source: a,
                target: b
            },
            l_bc = {
                source: b,
                target: c
            },
            l_ca = {
                source: c,
                target: a
            }
        links = [l_ab, l_bc, l_ca];

        var id = 0;

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
            .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
            .force('link', d3.forceLink())
            .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .alphaTarget(1)
            .on("tick", ticked)
            .stop();

        var g = svg.append("g"),
            link = g.append("g").attr("stroke", "#000").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".link"),
            node = g.append("g").attr("stroke", "#fff").attr("stroke-width", 1.5).selectAll(".node");

        function restart() {

            // Updates the node & link data after nodes & links update
            node = node.data(nodes);
            link = link.data(links);

            console.log(node);
            console.log(link);

            // Select all nodes & links that need removal
            // after data update mismatch with DOM
            node.exit().transition()
                .attr("r", 0)
                .remove();

            link.exit().transition()
                .attr("stroke-opacity", 0)
                .attrTween("x1", d => {
                    return function () {
                        return d.source.x;
                    };
                })
                .attrTween("x2", d => {
                    return function () {
                        return d.target.x;
                    };
                })
                .attrTween("y1", d => {
                    return function () {
                        return d.source.y;
                    };
                })
                .attrTween("y2", d => {
                    return function () {
                        return d.target.y;
                    };
                })
                .remove();

            node = node.enter().append("circle")
                .attr("fill", d => color(d.id))
                .call(node => node.transition().attr("r", 8))
                .merge(node);

            link = link.enter().append("line")
                .call(link => link.transition().attr("stroke-opacity", 1))
                .merge(link);

            // Update and restart the simulation.
            simulation.nodes(nodes);
            simulation.force("link").links(links)
            .strength(d => {
                console.log(d);
                return 1;
            });
            simulation.alpha(1).restart();
        }

        function ticked() {
            node.attr("cx", d => d.x)
                .attr("cy", d => d.y);

            link.attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
                .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
                .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
                .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);
        }

        restart();

        document.getElementById('btnRenderExisting3Node').addEventListener('click', function () {
            nodes = [a, b, c];
            links = [l_ab, l_bc, l_ca];
            restart();
        });

        document.getElementById('btnRenderExisting2Node').addEventListener('click', function () {
            nodes = [a, b];
            links = [l_ab];
            restart();
        });

        document.getElementById('btnRenderNewNode').addEventListener('click', function () {
            var d = {
                id: id++,
                x: width / 2,
                y: height / 2
            };
            nodes = [a, b, c, d];
            links = [l_ab, l_bc, l_ca, {
                source: a,
                target: d
            }];
            restart();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

